# Django test fixtures and content types

Tags: django, django-testing, django-contenttypes

I'm using django's **ContentType** foreign key in my model,
and I'm using it in the fixtures for unit tests.

Therefore, I have to hard-code **content_type_id** in my fixture, but django sometimes initializes it to a different value and thus my tests fail.

So is there a way to safely predict the **content_type_id** of the model or any other proper way to handle such situations?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use natural keys: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys

Most of the documentation refers to how to add the capability to your own models, but `ContentType` already supports them so just add [`--natural-foreign`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-dumpdata--natural-foreign) to your `dumpdata` management command:

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata myapp --indent=4 --natural-foreign
```

Comment: Thanks, a note that ``ContentType`` already have ``get_by_natural_key(app_label, model)`` is very useful.

Comment: Thanks, was stumped on this for a while. Also needed "--natural-primary" to get testing working.